# Is there anything wrong with correcting your Rabbi in front of other people?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, rabbis, kavod, sheker-false

If your Rabbi tells you something about Torah and you know that he is incorrect, and this has happened in the past and the Rabbi admitted his mistake, are you then allowed to correct the Rabbi if a third person is present?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%91

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3760/170

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Arakhin.16b.21

Comment: Does it fit into "המלבין פני חבירו"? And specifically "הכל לפי המבייש והמתבייש"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should correct him in an indirect way, reminding him of his earlier correct teaching or asking a question that leads in the right direction.

This is based on the Shulchan Aruch in [YD 242:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.242.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (my translation)

> ראה רבו עובר על דברי תורה אומר לו למדתני רבינו כך וכך
>   The one sees his Rav make a (Torah) mistake tells him "Rabbi, you taught
>   us so and so"

It is also in line with what the Rambam writes ([MT Mamrim 6:11](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1181857/jewish/Mamrim-Chapter-6.htm))

> If he sees his father violate Torah law, he should not tell him:
>   'Father, you transgressed Torah law.' Instead, he should tell him:
>   'Father, is not such-and-such written in the Torah?', as if he is
>   asking him, rather than warning him.

Comment: While everything is true it does not address the publicity problem at all! This Halachah applies in person. Please show how correcting the Rabbi in public is different.

Comment: Can you say more? From where do we know this *halacha* only applies in person? Why would it be different in public? I am not saying it is not true, I am just asking from where you say this. Thanks

Comment: What you brought falls under כיבוד רב, but mentions no  "המלבין פני חבירו"? And specifically "הכל לפי המבייש והמתבייש". I thought OP is especially interested in correcting publicly.

Comment: No I meant shaming the Rabbi himself, just as a regular person.

Comment: I understand. But who says that correcting him by reminding of his teachings or asking if it is not written otherwise would shame the rabbi? I can easily see how to do it in the matter of learning ("interesting that you say that, I remember you taught us that XXX, but maybe this different") thus avoiding any shame. Where do you see that the SA and MT teach in the context of a 1-1 situation?

Comment: I meant this too - I edited my comment